# как удалить ветку в git если в имя попал слэш

Tags: git, git-branch

случайно набрал в консоле не так и теперь не могу удалить неправильно названную ветку:

```
git branch
  develop
* master
  origin/admin-news
```

как мне удалить последнюю ветку (origin/admin-news)

Comment: два варианта - возьмите имя ветки в кавычик или перед слешем добавьте бекслеш (`origin\/admin-news`)

Comment: @KoVadim, у меня и без этого отлично работает. см. мой ответ.

Comment: да, я видел. Проверил, под линуксом все хорошо удаляется. Я было решил, что, смотря на `origin/admin-news`, git решит, что это удаленная (remote) ветка, а она локальная. Но гит в очередной раз удивил. Но в целом странно, обычно в имени ветки нельзя использовать символы, которые нельзя использовать в имени файла.

Посмотрел глубже. гит создал в каталоге `.git/refs/heads/` папку... оригинально.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

той же командой `branch`, но с опцией `-d`

создаём:

```
$ git branch origin/admin-news
$ git branch 
* master
  origin/admin-news
```

и удаляем:

```
$ git branch -d origin/admin-news
Deleted branch origin/admin-news (was 1ba85e8).
$ git branch 
* master
```

---

если в ответ на команду `git branch -d ...` вы получите сообщение вида:

> error: The branch 'origin/admin-news' is not fully merged.
>   If you are sure you want to delete it, run 'git branch -D origin/admin-news'.

и вы уверены, что уникальные коммиты в удаляемой ветке вам точно не нужны, то замените, как и предлагается в сообщении, опцию `-d` на `-D`:

```
$ git branch -D origin/admin-news
Deleted branch origin/admin-news (was a6f907d).
```

Comment: должна быть опция -D большая, на маленькую ругается:

Comment: @akalend, в man-е есть оговорка по поводу разницы между `-d` и `-D`, но я решил для краткости не расписывать так много. пожалуй, допишу.

Comment: спасибо за дополнение